# Get date from week number

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

Please what's wrong with my code:

```
import datetime
d = "2013-W26"
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-W%W")
print(r)
```

Display "2013-01-01 00:00:00", Thanks.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

A week number is not enough to generate a date; you need a day of the week as well. Add a default:

```
import datetime
d = "2013-W26"
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")
print(r)
```

The `-1` and `-%w` pattern tells the parser to pick the Monday in that week. This outputs:

```
2013-07-01 00:00:00
```

`%W` uses Monday as the first day of the week. While you can pick your own weekday, you may get unexpected results if you deviate from that.

See the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` behaviour](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) section in the documentation, footnote 4:

> When used with the `strptime()` method, `%U` and `%W` are only used in calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

Note, if your week number is a [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), you'll want to use `%G-W%V-%u` instead! Those directives require Python 3.6 or newer.

Comment: Does not work. datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-W0-0", "%Y-W%W-%w") == datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-W1-0", "%Y-W%W-%w") --> "2018-01-07 00:00:00".  1st and 2nd week of 2018 have the same start date.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd: that’s because there is no week 0 in 2018. Week 0 is the partial week before the first Monday of the year; in 2018 the first Monday is the 1st of January. In other words, *your input string* is the problem here, not the technique, and Python has error-corrected to interpret W0 to mean W1 instead.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd: If this is an issue for your app, you’ll need to special-case such years; `if d.endswith('-W0') and r.day == 7: raise ValueError('Invalid date string, No week 0 in {}'.format(r.year))`

Comment: Any idea how to deal with non zero padded week numbers? (e.g. 2020-w1, 2020-w52)

Comment: @MichaelH.: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Watch out if you're using ISO weeks! You'll need to use a different parse string as indicated at the bottom of the answer. Took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer: they are at the bottom because the question uses the non-ISO patterns.

Answer (score 49):

In Python 3.8 there is the handy `datetime.date.fromisocalendar`:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.fromisocalendar(2020, 1, 1)  # (year, week, day of week)
datetime.date(2019, 12, 30, 0, 0)
```

In older Python versions (3.7-) the calculation can use the information from  `datetime.date.isocalendar` to figure out the week ISO8601 compliant weeks:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def monday_of_calenderweek(year, week):
    first = date(year, 1, 1)
    base = 1 if first.isocalendar()[1] == 1 else 8
    return first + timedelta(days=base - first.isocalendar()[2] + 7 * (week - 1))
```

Both works also with `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: For 52/2023 it gives monday=2023-12-26 which is wrong year.

Answer (score 39):

To complete the other answers - if you are using *ISO* week numbers, this string is appropriate (to get the Monday of a given ISO week number):

```
import datetime
d = '2013-W26'
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + '-1', '%G-W%V-%u')
print(r)
```

`%G`, `%V`, `%u` are ISO equivalents of `%Y`, `%W`, `%w`, so this outputs:

```
2013-06-24 00:00:00
```

Availabe in Python 3.6+; from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime
res = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018 W30 w1", "%Y %W w%w")
print res
```

Adding of 1 as week day will yield exact current week start. Adding of timedelta(days=6) will gives you the week end.

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23)
```

Comment: @Senthikumar C that should be like below
`res = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018 W30 w1", "%Y W%W w%w")`

Comment: The accepted answer has a problem with the date 2021-01-04, it says it belongs to the year 2020

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for a simple function that returns all working days (Mo-Fr) dates from a week number consider this (based on [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087427/13083583))

```
import datetime

def weeknum_to_dates(weeknum):
    return [datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-W"+ str(weeknum) + str(x), "%Y-W%W-%w").strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for x in range(-5,0)]

weeknum_to_dates(37)
```

Output:

```
['17.09.2021', '16.09.2021', '15.09.2021', '14.09.2021', '13.09.2021']
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the yearly number of week, just add the number of weeks to the first day of the year.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

>>> week = 40
>>> year = 2019
>>> date = datetime.date(year,1,1)+relativedelta(weeks=+week)
>>> date
datetime.date(2019, 10, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which worked for me that accepts series data as opposed to `strptime` only accepting single string values:

```
#fw_to_date
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# fw is input in format 'YYYY-WW'
# Add weekday number to string 1 = Monday
fw = fw + '-1'
# dt is output column 
# Use %G-%V-%w if input is in ISO format
dt = pd.to_datetime(fw, format='%Y-%W-%w', errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [handy function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194745/get-first-and-last-day-of-given-week-number-in-python) including the issue with zero-week.