# Is Python's `datetime.strptime` buggy for week numbers on years with 53 weeks?

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

I am using Python 2.7 and I am trying to convert week numbers to actual dates.

I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087427/295307) solution which worked fine for basics tests, but I found a case where there seems to be a break: in years with 53 weeks.

The example below shows the issue:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime( "2015-W53-0", "%Y-W%W-%w").strftime("%Y-W%W-%w")
```

This returns `'2016-W01-0'`, which I think does not make sense.

Is this a known issue, is there a known workaround?

Note that:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime( "2015-W53-0", "%Y-W%W-%w").isocalendar()
```

yields `(2016, 1, 7)`, so it's probably `strptime` which is guessing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a good library called [`isoweek`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/1.0.1) which works as I expect.

```
#This is Week 53 of 2015 according to ISO
week = isoweek.Week.withdate( datetime.date( 2016,1,1) )
monday = week.monday()
print monday.isocalendar()
#Prints (2015, 53, 1), which is correct.
```

I think this is the simplest way to handle these issues.

Comment: This works, thanks for posting the solution. You might accept your own answer for this question. It's a shame that `strptime` doesn't support the `%G` and `%V` for ISO dates *James K* mentions (at least not in Python 3.5.2).

Answer (score 1):

%W is the week of the year, with the first week containing a Monday counted as week 1.

The first day of the week is Monday, which has a %w day number of 1. The last day of the week is Sunday, which has a day number of 0. So in this reckoning %Y-%W-0 always comes six days later than %Y-%W-1.

By this reckoning, the 52nd week starts on the 28th of December, and doesn't contain a Sunday. So 2015-W52-0 is interpreted as the first Sunday in 2016 (Jan 3rd). Since this is before the first Monday, 2015-W52-0 is canonically 2016-W00-0 and 2015-W53-0 is the second Sunday in 2016, which is at the end of week 1, ie Jan 10th, or 2016-W01-0.

So the methods are working as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

The %W and %w don't implement the ISO week date algorithm, which sets the first week as that containing a Thursday. 2015 contains a 53rd week by the ISO method, but not by the %W method. If you want to use ISO weekdates you should use `isocalendar`.

Since the standard implementation of python is just calling the C library functions, you may be able to use %G (The year) and %V (the week number) according to the ISO algorithm. But these can't be guaranteed to be portable.