# Group by weeks, months, days

Tags: django

I would like to group querysets by a date interval according to a datetime attribute of the model. I want to show average values from the model on a day-to-day, week-by-week and month-by-month basis.

E.g.

- Week commencing 01/01/2017 - average distance: 30
- Week commencing 08/01/2017 - average distance: 40
  ...

Can this be achieved with the standard Django queryset API?

Answer (score 25):

Assuming the following model which might match your description

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    distance  = models.IntegerField()
```

You can achieve a week by week statistic with the following query

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeek, ExtractYear
from django.db.models import Sum, Count

stats = (Activity.objects
    .annotate(year=ExtractYear('timestamp'))
    .annotate(week=ExtractWeek('timestamp'))
    .values('year', 'week')
    .annotate(avg_distance=Avg('distance'))
)
```

Sample output

```
<QuerySet [{'year': 2018, 'week': 31, 'distance': 3.2}]>
```

To recover the first day of week, check [Get date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number)

In particular:

```
for record in stats:
    week = "{year}-W{week}-1".format(year=record['year'], week=record['week'])
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(week, "%Y-W%W-%w")
```

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Great answer, saved me a lot of time!
 
The only problem is python week numbering vs Postgres/ISO.

2020-01-01 in python is in week 0:
` datetime.datetime(2020,1,1).strftime("%Y-W%W-%w")      '2020-W00-3'`
while in Postgres it is in week 1: ` select extract('week' from '2020-01-01'::date) as week;
       week 
      ------
          1
`;
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12.4/functions-datetime.html#week

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of field lookups specifically for date/datetime fields: [week](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week), [day](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date), [month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month) (should be combined with [year](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year)) etc.