# Parsing YYYY-WW to Timestamp to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to parse dates on the format `YYYY-WW` to a `Timestamp` but this just yields the start date of the year, like so:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime('2015-09', format='%Y-%W')
Out[11]: Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, how can I yield the "first day starting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify also day of week:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('2015-09' + '-0', format='%Y-%W-%w'))
2015-03-08 00:00:00

print (pd.to_datetime('2015-09' + '-1', format='%Y-%W-%w'))
2015-03-02 00:00:00

print (pd.to_datetime('2015-09' + '-2', format='%Y-%W-%w'))
2015-03-03 00:00:00
```

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17087314/2901002).

Answer (score 1):

1.The behaviour is ok.

```
pd.to_datetime('2015-09', format='%Y-%W', dayfirst='True')

Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00')
```

2.you can try this.

```
pd.to_datetime([1, 2, 3], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('1960-01-01'))

DatetimeIndex(['1960-01-02', '1960-01-03', '1960-01-04'], type='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```