# Pandas: How to create a datetime object from Week and Year?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have a dataframe that provides two integer columns with the Year and Week of the year:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
L1 = [43,44,51,2,5,12]
L2 = [2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Week":L1,"Year":L2})

df
Out[72]: 
   Week  Year
0    43  2016
1    44  2016
2    51  2016
3     2  2017
4     5  2017
5    12  2017
```

I need to create a datetime-object from these two numbers.

I tried this, but it throws an error:

```
df["DT"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.datetime64(x.Year,'Y') + np.timedelta64(x.Week,'W'),axis=1)
```

Then I tried this, it works but gives the wrong result, that is it ignores the week completely:

```
df["S"] = df.Week.astype(str)+'-'+df.Year.astype(str)
df["DT"] = df["S"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,format='%W-%Y'))

df
Out[74]: 
   Week  Year        S         DT
0    43  2016  43-2016 2016-01-01
1    44  2016  44-2016 2016-01-01
2    51  2016  51-2016 2016-01-01
3     2  2017   2-2017 2017-01-01
4     5  2017   5-2017 2017-01-01
5    12  2017  12-2017 2017-01-01
```

I'm really getting lost between Python's `datetime`, Numpy's `datetime64`, and pandas `Timestamp`, can you tell me how it's done correctly?

I'm using Python 3, if that is relevant in any way.

EDIT:

Starting with Python 3.8 the problem is easily solved with a newly introduced method on datetime.date objects: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar

Comment: Are the `Week` values [ISO week numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) or do they represent units of 7 days?

Comment: Initially I have timestamps in `s`, they are converted using `pd.to_datetime()`, the week is then extracted by using `dt.week` on the Timestamp.

Comment: There is a subtle pitfall here -- If `s` contains the date `2016-1-1`, then its ISO week number (returned by `dt.week`) is 53, and its ISO year (which you didn't record) is 2015. If you try to reconstitute the date using the year 2016 and ISO week 53, then you get 2017-01-02 (assuming Monday begins the week). So you can't roundtrip correctly unless you also record the ISO year (which is not always the same as the actual year.)

Comment: @unutbu Thanks, this is good to know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [19]: pd.to_datetime(df.Year.astype(str), format='%Y') + \
             pd.to_timedelta(df.Week.mul(7).astype(str) + ' days')
Out[19]:
0   2016-10-28
1   2016-11-04
2   2016-12-23
3   2017-01-15
4   2017-02-05
5   2017-03-26
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

> Initially I have timestamps in `s`

It's much easier to parse it from UNIX epoch timestamp:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UNIX_Time'], unit='s')
```

**Timing** for 10M rows DF:

Setup:

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1970-01-01', freq='1T', periods=10**7), columns=['date'])

In [27]: df.shape
Out[27]: (10000000, 1)

In [28]: df['unix_ts'] = df['date'].astype(np.int64)//10**9

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
                       date    unix_ts
0       1970-01-01 00:00:00          0
1       1970-01-01 00:01:00         60
2       1970-01-01 00:02:00        120
3       1970-01-01 00:03:00        180
4       1970-01-01 00:04:00        240
5       1970-01-01 00:05:00        300
6       1970-01-01 00:06:00        360
7       1970-01-01 00:07:00        420
8       1970-01-01 00:08:00        480
9       1970-01-01 00:09:00        540
...                     ...        ...
9999990 1989-01-05 10:30:00  599999400
9999991 1989-01-05 10:31:00  599999460
9999992 1989-01-05 10:32:00  599999520
9999993 1989-01-05 10:33:00  599999580
9999994 1989-01-05 10:34:00  599999640
9999995 1989-01-05 10:35:00  599999700
9999996 1989-01-05 10:36:00  599999760
9999997 1989-01-05 10:37:00  599999820
9999998 1989-01-05 10:38:00  599999880
9999999 1989-01-05 10:39:00  599999940

[10000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Check:

```
In [31]: pd.to_datetime(df.unix_ts, unit='s')
Out[31]:
0         1970-01-01 00:00:00
1         1970-01-01 00:01:00
2         1970-01-01 00:02:00
3         1970-01-01 00:03:00
4         1970-01-01 00:04:00
5         1970-01-01 00:05:00
6         1970-01-01 00:06:00
7         1970-01-01 00:07:00
8         1970-01-01 00:08:00
9         1970-01-01 00:09:00
                  ...
9999990   1989-01-05 10:30:00
9999991   1989-01-05 10:31:00
9999992   1989-01-05 10:32:00
9999993   1989-01-05 10:33:00
9999994   1989-01-05 10:34:00
9999995   1989-01-05 10:35:00
9999996   1989-01-05 10:36:00
9999997   1989-01-05 10:37:00
9999998   1989-01-05 10:38:00
9999999   1989-01-05 10:39:00
Name: unix_ts, Length: 10000000, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Timing:

```
In [32]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df.unix_ts, unit='s')
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** I think 156 milliseconds for converting 10.000.000 rows is not that slow

Comment: Maybe directly using the timestamps is a better idea indeed. However I'm working with tens of millions of lines, and the `datetime` stuff is notoriously slow.

Comment: @Khris, yes, using this method we can convert it precisely

Comment: @Khris, i've added timing - please check

Comment: Initially I'm doing a conversion at one point and then save all values to avoid having to do later conversions. But I didn't anticipate I would need to convert back like that, so it's probably the best to directly go from the epoch timestamps.

Comment: @MaxU - Can you compare week solutions? Because question is about converting with `week` and `year`.

Comment: @jezrael, please read OP's comment to their own question - `Initially I have timestamps in __s__`

Comment: Your solution is indeed fast: `165 ms ± 1.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: Interesting thing, if I first do `df["Test"] = pd.to_datetime(df.unix_ts, unit='s')` and then time this `%timeit df.Test.dt.date` it gets really slow:
`18.9 s ± 370 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. Turns out it seems to be the `dt`-access that's so slow.

Comment: @Khris, yeah, that's interesting, thanks for update!

Answer (score 13):

Like @Gianmario Spacagna mentioned for datetimes higher like 2018 use `%V` with `%G`:

```
L1 = [43,44,51,2,5,12,52,53,1,2,5,52]
L2 = [2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Week":L1,"Year":L2})


df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Week.astype(str)+
                           df.Year.astype(str).add('-1') ,format='%V%G-%u')
print (df)
    Week  Year        new
0     43  2016 2016-10-24
1     44  2016 2016-10-31
2     51  2016 2016-12-19
3      2  2017 2017-01-09
4      5  2017 2017-01-30
5     12  2017 2017-03-20
6     52  2018 2018-12-24
7     53  2018 2018-12-31
8      1  2019 2018-12-31
9      2  2019 2019-01-07
10     5  2019 2019-01-28
11    52  2019 2019-12-23
```

Comment: Weird, the docs imply that the first day is already defined by using `%W` or `%U`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: This approach only works until year 2018. It is not compliant with ISO-8601 because the 31st December 2018 is assigned to week 53 of 2018 instead of week 1 of 2019. Causing all of the subsequent datetimes to be shifted by 7 days.

Comment: @GianmarioSpacagna - Can you explian more?

Comment: Try with Year = 2019 and Week = 1 and it will return 2019-01-07 as date. The correct date should be 2018-12-31. Source: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019

Comment: I think the solution for ISO weeks is in using a different format string (%G-W%V-%u) as documented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087427/2919826

Answer (score 6):

There is something fishy going on with weeks starting from 2019. The ISO-8601 standard assigns the 31st December 2018 to the week 1 of year 2019. The other approaches based on:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Week.astype(str)+
                  df.Year.astype(str).add('-2') ,format='%W%Y-%w')
```

will give shifted results starting from 2019.

In order to be compliant with the ISO-8601 standard you would have to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

L1 = [52,53,1,2,5,52]
L2 = [2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Week":L1,"Year":L2})
df['ISO'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-W' + df['Week'].astype(str) + '-1'
df['DT'] = df['ISO'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%G-W%V-%u"))
print(df)
```

It prints:

```
   Week  Year         ISO         DT
0    52  2018  2018-W52-1 2018-12-24
1    53  2018  2018-W53-1 2018-12-31
2     1  2019   2019-W1-1 2018-12-31
3     2  2019   2019-W2-1 2019-01-07
4     5  2019   2019-W5-1 2019-01-28
5    52  2019  2019-W52-1 2019-12-23
```

The week 53 of 2018 is ignored and mapped to the week 1 of 2019.

Please verify yourself on https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019.

Comment: Good observation. Python 3.8 introduces a new method on datetime.date objects that solves the entire problem: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar

Comment: Thanks @Khris. Unfortunately, most enterprise applications run on python 3.6 as most of the cloud providers currently support for managed environments but good to know for the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow [ISO Week Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

> Weeks start with Monday. Each week's year is the Gregorian year in
> which the Thursday falls. The first week of the year, hence, always
> contains 4 January. ISO week year numbering therefore slightly
> deviates from the Gregorian for some days close to 1 January.

The following sample code, generates a sequence of 60 Dates, starting from 18Dec2016 Sun and adds the appropriate columns.

It adds:

- A "Date"
- Week Day of the "Date"
- Finds the Week Starting Monday of that "Date"
- Finds the Year of the Week Starting Monday of that "Date"
- Adds a Week Number (ISO)
- Gets the Starting Monday Date, from Year and Week Number

Sample Code Below:

```
# Generate Some Dates
dft1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2016-12-18', freq='D', periods=60))
dft1.columns = ['e_FullDate']
dft1['e_FullDateWeekDay'] = dft1.e_FullDate.dt.day_name().str.slice(0,3)


#Add a Week Start Date (Monday)
dft1['e_week_start'] = dft1['e_FullDate'] - pd.to_timedelta(dft1['e_FullDate'].dt.weekday,
                                                      unit='D')
dft1['e_week_startWeekDay'] = dft1.e_week_start.dt.day_name().str.slice(0,3)

#Add a Week Start Year
dft1['e_week_start_yr'] = dft1.e_week_start.dt.year

#Add a Week Number of Week Start Monday
dft1['e_week_no'] = dft1['e_week_start'].dt.week

#Add a Week Start generate from Week Number and Year
dft1['e_week_start_from_week_no'] = pd.to_datetime(dft1.e_week_no.astype(str)+
                  dft1.e_week_start_yr.astype(str).add('-1') ,format='%W%Y-%w')
dft1['e_week_start_from_week_noWeekDay'] = dft1.e_week_start_from_week_no.dt.day_name().str.slice(0,3)


with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999, 'display.max_columns', 0, 'display.max_colwidth', 9999):
    display(dft1)
```

[image]