# Combining Columns in Isoweek Object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a year and week column:

```
year     week
2018     18
2019     17
2019     17
```

I'm trying to combine the year and week columns into a new 'isoweek' column using the [isoweek](https://pypi.org/project/isoweek/) library.  I can't seem to figure out how to properly loop through the rows to create the object column.  If I do something like:

```
df['isoweek'] = Week(df['year'],df['week'])
```

isoweek chokes on the vectorization.  I've tried creating a basic list and appending it to my dataframe, like so:

```
 obj_list = []

 for i in range(500):
     year = df['year'][i]
     week = df['week'][i]
     w = Week(year,week)
     obj_list.append(w)

 df['isoweek'] = obj_list
```

But I end up with a simple tuple in the column.

The goal is to be able to use some of the isoweek library's operations to calculate date differences, like:

```
 df['isoweek'] - 4 
 >isoweek.Week(2019, 34)
```

Is it even possible to store an object like this in a dataframe column?  If so, how does one go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use the built in method for datetime:

```
df['week_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str), format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df['week'].mul(7).astype(str) + ' days')

# Output:
    week    year    week_start
0   18  2018    2018-05-07
1   17  2019    2019-04-30
2   17  2019    2019-04-30
```

Calculating time differences is pretty straightforward here:

```
# Choose 7 weeks
n_weeks = pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='W')

# Adding is simple
df['week_start'] + n_weeks

# Output
0   2018-06-25
1   2019-06-18
2   2019-06-18
```

> For more on this, read: [***Pandas: How to create a datetime object from Week and Year?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436873/pandas-how-to-create-a-datetime-object-from-week-and-year?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you could do this

First, set up the example dataframe

```
from isoweek import Week
df = pd.DataFrame ({'year' : [2018,2019,2019], 
                    'week' : [18,17,17]})
```

Loop through the dataframe, adding the isoweek to a list

```
ls_isoweek = []
for row in df.itertuples(): 
    ls_isoweek.append(Week(row[1],row[2]))
```

The list looks like this

```
[isoweek.Week(2018, 18), isoweek.Week(2019, 17), isoweek.Week(2019, 17)]
```

This list can be accessed thusly

```
ls_isoweek[0] - 4
```

Produces this output

```
isoweek.Week(2018, 14)
```

However, the list can also be added back to the dataframe if you wish

```
df['isoweek'] = ls_isoweek
```

You can then do things like ...

```
df['isoweek_minus_4'] = df['isoweek'].apply(lambda x: x-4)
```

Producing an output like the below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but if anyone else is still looking to use a solution of this form as I was, you could use lambda functions along with apply. For the dataframe below (with int64 dtypes),

```
    year   week
0   2018    18
1   2019    17
2   2019    17
```

Now we use isoweek to appropriately parse the data,

```
from isoweek import Week
df.apply(lambda row : Week(row["year"],row["week"]),axis=1)
```

This produces the output,

```
0    (2018, 18)
1    (2019, 17)
2    (2019, 17)
dtype: object
```

You could also identify the (week,year) with a datetime object by combining this approach with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687085.

```
df.apply(lambda row : Week(int(row["year"]),int(row["week"])).monday(),axis=1)
```

The int appears a little redundant there, but pandas by default uses int64 which doesn't appear to function with isoweek correctly. This produces the output,

```
0    2018-04-30
1    2019-04-22
2    2019-04-22
dtype: object
```