# Converting a year and week number to the date of the Monday of the week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-dateutil

I am trying to get the date of the Monday of the week from a week number and a year. I put together some sample code to first do what I want and then to apply it, but I get this error:

```
Unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

Can someone please explain how to fix this error? Here is some sample code:

```
#this gives me the result that I want
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

week = 1
year = 2021
date = datetime.date(year, 1, 4) + relativedelta(weeks=+week)
print(date)
# date = 2021-01-11
```

Here is where I am failing:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
                    'week' : [1],
                    'year' : [2021]})
test['Date'] = datetime.date(test['year'], 1, 4) + relativedelta(weeks=+test['week'])
```

Result:

```
error: TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

Comment: `test['week'][0]`?

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436873/pandas-how-to-create-a-datetime-object-from-week-and-year