# How to check dates basing on year and week number in Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'd like to check the days for a given week_number.
For an instance, if I input year 2017 and weekNumber 43, I would like to receive all dates for that week, in this case 22-28.10.2017.

Is it possible to do in Python? Was trying to find something using google, but unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087427/8560382

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def get_start_end_dates(year, week):
     d = date(year,1,1)
     if(d.weekday()<= 3):
         d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())             
     else:
         d = d + timedelta(7-d.weekday())
     dlt = timedelta(days = (week-1)*7)
     return d + dlt,  d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)

print get_start_end_dates(2017,43)
```

Python 3

```
# From monday to sunday

from datetime import date, timedelta
def get_start_end_dates(year, week):
     d = date(year,1,1)
     if(d.weekday()<= 3):
         d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())             
     else:
         d = d + timedelta(7-d.weekday())
     dlt = timedelta(days = (week-1)*7)
     return d + dlt,  d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)

print(get_start_end_dates(2023,6))


# From sunday to saturday

from datetime import date, timedelta
def get_start_end_dates(year, week):
     d = date(year,1,1)
     if(d.weekday()<= 3):
         d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())             
     else:
         d = d + timedelta(6-d.weekday())
     dlt = timedelta(days = (week-1)*7)
     return d + dlt,  d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)

print(get_start_end_dates(2023,6))
```

Comment: I works great, but is there a possibility to start a week from Sunday, not Monday ?

Comment: Okay, I changed one line of code to d = d + timedelta(6-d.weekday()) and it's working. Thanks