# bokeh server- alternate from datetime axis to categorical on Selection

Tags: pandas, datetime, bokeh

I have two dataframes as two different `ColumnDataSources` for updating plots. One looks like

```
ENTRYDATE | Transactions
2017-01-01  290
2017-01-03  20
..
2018-02-04  118
```

The other dataframe's first column is a float of the first dataframe consisting of the year, followed by the week number of that year, separated by a colon

```
ENTRYDATE | Transactions
2017.1      310
2018.1      118
```

I have a Select Widget that updates a line plot based on whether the user wants to view daily data or weekly data. The daily plot renders fine. However, when `weekly` is selected, the plot treats the weeks as number data there are large gaps from one data point to the next (i.e. 2017.52 to 2018.1)

How can I edit my code so that when the user makes a selection, the weekly data is presented categorically? Is there a better way to represent weeks across several calendar years?

Here is the relevant piece of my code:

```
dfdate=(df2.groupby([df2['ENTRYDATE'].dt.date]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))
#WEEK
df['YearWk']=df['ENTRYDATE'].dt.strftime('%Y.%W') #add year column
dfweek=(df.groupby([df['YearWk']]).size().reset_index(name='Transactions'))
dfweek.columns.values[0]='ENTRYDATE' #rename column to ENTRYDATE 
dfweek.sort_values('ENTRYDATE',ascending=True) #sort by Year.WeekNumber

sourceDay=ColumnDataSource(data=dfdate)
sourceWeek=ColumnDataSource(data=dfweek)

p=figure(plot_width=800,plot_height=500, y_axis_label="Transaction Count",
x_axis_label="Date",background_fill_color='beige')
p.line(x="ENTRYDATE",y="Transactions",color='blue', source=sourceDay)
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter()

#update function
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if new=='Daily': 
        sourceDay.data={"ENTRYDATE":dfdate["ENTRYDATE"],"Transactions":dfdate["Transactions"]}
    elif new=='Weekly':
        sourceDay.data=sourceWeek.data
        p.x_range=str(dfweek["ENTRYDATE"].tolist())

#selecttool
select=Select(title='Choose Your Time Interval:', options=['Daily','Weekly'], value='daily')
select.on_change('value',update_plot)
layout=row(select, p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

I've tried setting an x_range via `p.x_range=dfweek["ENTRYDATE"].tolist()` and `p.x_range.set=dfweek["ENTRYDATE"].tolist()` but no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the week and year to datetime via
`df = pd.to_datetime(df.YearWk.add('-0'), format='%Y-%W-%w')` as per
[Parsing week of year to datetime objects with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931749/parsing-week-of-year-to-datetime-objects-with-pandas)