# How do I extract last day of week from yyyyww column in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a df_mixed column containing data in yyyyww format, eg: 201501, 201502…etc
I have to extract the last date of the week and put it in ds column.

For eg: For 201501, last day of week 1 is 4-1-2015
For 201502, last day is 11-1-2015

I have to follow the ISO format.
According to the ISO format the 1st week of 2015 starts from 29th December 2014 and ends on 4th January 2015

Any idea how to go about it using python, pandas and datetime library?

Comment: Do you require the last day of all weeks in the particular month or is there a criteria?

Comment: duplicate of [Get first and last day of given week number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194746/10513549)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first and last day of given week number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194745/get-first-and-last-day-of-given-week-number-in-python)

Comment: I think the question is `Pandas` specific and thus not that duplicate

Comment: @VidyaGanesh Yes I need the last days for all the weeks given in the dataset i.e. from 201501 to 201805.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use `pd.to_datetime` to construct the datetime in format `%Y%W%w`. I added `0` as the weekday since you want Sundays which is first day of a week:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[201501, 201502]})

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime((df["Date"]-1).astype(str)+"0", format="%Y%W%w")

print (df)

        Date
0 2015-01-04
1 2015-01-11
```

Comment: I am getting an error of operands. Maybe it's because of my dataset

Comment: Can I somehow share the dataset with you?  The error just says  - 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: It probably means your date column is type ‘str’. I did a minus 1 in order to get the correct result, so all you need to do is ‘astype(int)’ first before -1.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['201501', '201502']})
```

If you choose Sunday as the last day of week:

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+'Sun', format='%Y%W%a')
df
```

output:

```
     date      date2
0  201501 2015-01-11
1  201502 2015-01-18
```

*NB. if you want American week format, use `%U` in place of `%W` and `Mon` as the last day of week. See the doc for [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more precisions*

Comment: By doing this, I am getting 11-01-2015 for 201501 instead of 4-01-2015.

Comment: I think by adding 'Sun' it is counting additional 7 days

Comment: According to the ISO format, the first week starts from 29th dec of last year to 4th Jan of the present

Comment: I see that, this is unexpected. I honestly don't see the reason why. This seems like a bug to me

Comment: Have you tested 0/%w in place of Sun/%a like @HenryYik suggested?

Comment: Alternatively you could subtract 7 days to the result with pd.Timedelta if this difference is always the same

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for helping!