# How to convert string dataframe column to datetime as format with year and week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Sample Data:

```
Week      Price
2011-31    1.58
2011-32    1.9
2011-33    1.9
2011-34    1.9
```

I have a dataframe like above and I wanna convert 'Week' column type from string to datetime.

My Code:

```
data['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Week, format='%Y-%W')
data = data.drop(['Week'], axis=1)
data.index = data.Date_Time
```

Error:

> 'ValueError: Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need specify day of week by parameter [`%w`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087427/2901002):

```
data['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Week + '0', format='%Y-%W%w')
print (data)
      Week  Price  Date_Time
0  2011-31   1.58 2011-08-07
1  2011-32   1.90 2011-08-14
2  2011-33   1.90 2011-08-21
3  2011-34   1.90 2011-08-28
```

For `DatetimeIndex` use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with `rename`:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.pop('Week') + '0', format='%Y-%W%w').rename('Date')
print (data)
            Price
Date             
2011-08-07   1.58
2011-08-14   1.90
2011-08-21   1.90
2011-08-28   1.90
```

Comment: You are correct but I also want to see week number in datetime formated column like 2011-31-1. How can I do that?

Comment: @EmreBEGEN - hmmm, dates have only `YYYY-MM-DD` in python. Eg. for last date `2011-34-1` not exist. Can you explain more?

Comment: My mistake. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`%W` uses Monday as the first day of the week.

```
import datetime
week = '2011-31'
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(week + '-1', "%Y-%W-%w")
print(date)
```

See this:https://repl.it/@ibrahimth/EvergreenNutritiousEmbeds

Comment: OK, so simple question - Do you think your answer working for OP, he/she need `How to convert string dataframe column to datetime as format with year and week?` ? Or not?

Comment: @jezrael his problem is that `''ValueError: Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year'` and the code solve it.