# Get week start date from week number

Tags: python

This question is related to [Get date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17087314), and is possibly a duplicate of the latter, however, I think what is suggested in the accepted answer to that question does not really work.

```
In [6]: datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-18-1', "%Y-%W-%w")
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 6, 0, 0)
```

Notice how it returns Monday 2019-5-6. However, according to the calendar (I use http://whatweekisit.org for reference), 2019-5-6 the Monday of week 19.

Similarly, the example provided in the original question:

```
In [7]: datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-26-1', "%Y-%W-%w")
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 1, 0, 0)
```

According to http://whatweekisit.org/calendar-2013.html 2013-7-1 is the Monday of week 27.

Also

```
In [8]: datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-18-1', "%Y-%W-%w").isocalendar()[1]
Out[8]: 19
```

Notice how I give week 18 to `strptime`, and get week 19 back from `isocalendar`.

I am completely lost and would very much appreciate if someone could explain what is going on here. My original goal though is to get week start date from week number.

Comment: I sounds to me like you are explaining an off by 1 error. If so, couldn't you just subtract one from the result?

Comment: @Reedinationer I could of course, but I would like to understand why exactly it works like this. I doubt that it is a bug in Python.

Comment: What weeknumber is used depends on certain cultural things - for one which day starts a week? Sunday or monday?  sometimes week1  starts in the last year. from the docu of isocalender: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar **For example, 2004 begins on a Thursday, so the first week of ISO year 2004 begins on Monday, 29 Dec 2003 and ends on Sunday, 4 Jan 2004, so that date(2003, 12, 29).isocalendar() == (2004, 1, 1) and date(2004, 1, 4).isocalendar() == (2004, 1, 7).**

Answer (score 2):

Based off of my testing, `datetime` does not consider the first week of 2019 (i.e. Jan 1-Jan 6) as week 1 because it isn't a full week; December 31st, 2018 is part of the week but is not in 2019. I suppose you'll have to accomodate for that by checking the output of `datetime.datetime.strptime('year-1-1', "%Y-%W-%w") == datetime.datetime.strptime('year-0-1', "%Y-%W-%w")`. If false, subtract 1.

2018 is an example of a year where `datetime` does return the same value as `isocalendar` because the first Monday of the year is Jan 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the isocalendar [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar):

> The ISO year consists of 52 or 53 full weeks, and where a week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. The first week of an ISO year is the first (Gregorian) calendar week of a year containing a Thursday. This is called week number 1, and the ISO year of that Thursday is the same as its Gregorian year.

---

On the other hand, `strptime` starts from the first full week, in fact, since 2019 starts from Tuesday, they start from different weeks:

```
import datetime as dt
strp_first = dt.datetime.strptime('2019-1-1', "%Y-%W-%w")

>>> print(strp_first)
2019-01-07 00:00:00

>>> print(strp_first.isocalendar()[1])
2
```

While in 2021, which starts from Friday:

```
strp_first = dt.datetime.strptime('2021-1-1', "%Y-%W-%w")

>>> print(strp_first)
2021-01-04 00:00:00

>>> print(strp_first.isocalendar()[1])
1
```