# Combining year, month, week number and day to date

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have the below dataframe:

```
year  month  week_num    day
2019   8       31       Thurs
2019   8       31        Fri
2019   8       32        Tues
```

The day abbreviations are `Mon`, `Tues`, `Weds`, `Thurs`, `Fri`, `Sat`, `Sun`.

I want to generate another column which will provide me the date in yyyy-mm-dd format. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide any code producing the dataframe so code to provide the yyyy-mm-dd format can be added.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the initial format that I have. I didn't write the code to separate it

Comment: The `month` column seems superfluous. What should be done if the other columns conflict with `month`?

Comment: You are right. `week_num` includes the information of `month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) gives you this opportunity. [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number) explains how to get the date from the week number.

Then, you can define a function to get the date and apply it to you dataframe.

Here the code:

```
# Import modules
import datetime

# Your data
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   [2019, 8, 29, "Fri"],
                    [2019, 8, 31, "Sun"],
                   [2019, 8, 29, "Tues"]],
                  columns=["year", "month", "week_num", "day"])

# A value per day
val_day = {"Mon": 0, "Tues": 1, "Weds": 2, "Thurs": 3,
           "Fri": 4, "Sat": 5, "Sun": 6}

# Get the date from the year, number of week and the day


def getDate(row):
    # Create string format
    str_date = "{0}-W{1}-1".format(row.year,
                                     row.week_num - 1)
    print(str_date)
    # Get the date
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        str_date, "%Y-W%W-%w") + datetime.timedelta(days=val_day[row.day])
    # Update date field
    row["date"] = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return row


# apply the function to each row
df = df.apply(getDate, axis=1)
print(df)
#    year  month  week_num    day        date
# 0  2019      8         1  Thurs  2019-01-03
# 1  2019      8        29    Fri  2019-07-19
# 2  2019      8        29   Tues  2019-07-16
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre, the error that I get: `ValueError: ("time data '2019-W30-7' does not match format '%Y-W%W-%w'", 'occurred at index 108')`

Comment: Do you know which date is rising this error ? The first date ? You can add `print(str_date)` after creating `str_date` in `getDate()`

Comment: The index 108 has the year 2019, month 8, week_num 31 and day Sun.

Comment: `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'day'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: Are you sure to have a column named `day` in your dataframe ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that. Now it generates all the dates like `2019-W31-1`

Comment: Actually it always generates one day later than it supposed to. For instance year 2019, week_num 31 and Thurs supposed to generate 2019-08-01 but it is 2019-08-02. How can I substract one day from all?

Comment: Are you running the last answer ? (with values for `Monday:0`, `Tuesday:1` ...)