# Pandas parse week numbers

Tags: pandas, datetime

Consider the following file `test.csv`:

```
"Time","RegionCode","RegionName","NumValue"
"2009-W40","AT","Austria",0
"2009-W40","BE","Belgium",54
"2009-W40","BG","Bulgaria",0
"2009-W40","CZ","Czech Republic",1
```

I'd like to parse the date which is stored in the first column and would like to create a dataframe like so:

```py
parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-W%W")
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=["Time"], date_parser=parser)
```

Result:

```
    Time    RegionCode  RegionName  NumValue
0   2009-01-01  AT  Austria 0
1   2009-01-01  BE  Belgium 54
2   2009-01-01  BG  Bulgaria    0
3   2009-01-01  CZ  Czech Republic  1
```

However, the resulting time column is not correct. All I get is "2019-01-01" and this is certainly not the 40th week of the year. Am I doing something wrong? Anybody else had this issue when parsing weeks?

Comment: Possible duplicate , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number

Comment: Thanks, changing the line to `parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x+"-1", "%Y-W%W-%w")` solved my issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct. The only problem is that from a week number and year, you cannot determine a specific date. The trick is to just add day of the week as 1.

I would recommend sticking with `pd.to_datetime()` like you tried initially and supplying a [date-format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). That should work out fine with the added 1:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time'] + '-1', format='%Y-W%W-%w')
# 0   2009-10-05
# 1   2009-10-05
# 2   2009-10-05
# 3   2009-10-05
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can parse it directly upon `read_csv`, but you can certainly do it after:

```
import pandas as pd

test = [
["2009-W40","AT","Austria",0],
["2009-W40","BE","Belgium",54],
["2009-W40","BG","Bulgaria",0],
["2009-W40","CZ","Czech Republic",1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(test,columns=["Time","RegionCode","RegionName","NumValue"])

df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"].str[:4],format="%Y") + \
             pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"].str[-2:].astype(int).mul(7),unit="days")

print (df)

#
        Time RegionCode      RegionName  NumValue
0 2009-10-08         AT         Austria         0
1 2009-10-08         BE         Belgium        54
2 2009-10-08         BG        Bulgaria         0
3 2009-10-08         CZ  Czech Republic         1
```