# I'd like to create a flag from a time field having the format YEARWEEKNUM

Tags: python

`201705` is the 5th week of year 2017, and 1st week of the month of March. (Year starts in FEB)

```
YRWKNUM   BEGIN_OF_MONTH   END_OF_MONTH

201701         1                 0
201702         0                 0 
201703         0                 0
201704         0                 1
201705         1                 0
201706         0                 0
201707         0                 0
201708         0                 0
201709         1                 1
201710         0                 0
201711         0                 0
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number