# pandas - how to slice a dataframe based on a column that has 'week number of year - year'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> my_df.loc[600:614,'Week-Year']
600    39-2018
601    39-2018
602    40-2018
603    40-2018
604    41-2018
605    41-2018
606    42-2018
607    42-2018
608    43-2018
609    43-2018
610    44-2018
611    44-2018
612    45-2018
613    45-2018
614    46-2018
```

The column is basically 'week number of year - year'. I now want to slice this dataframe from certain week to certain week.

Here's what i tried:

```
>>> end_date = datetime(2013, 4, 30)
>>> my_df.loc[(my_df['Week-Year'] <= end_date.strftime('%M-%Y'))]
```

But, this returns nothing. So, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is necessary convert `Week-Year` to datetimes:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(my_df['Week-Year'].add('_1'), format='%W-%Y_%w')
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033252/2901002
#ISO week numbers (ISO 8601 week definitions)
d = pd.to_datetime(my_df['Week-Year'].add('_1'), format='%V-%G_%u')
```

And then filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = my_df[d <= end_date]
```