# python datetime strptime unexpected output

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2015.18', "%Y.%W")
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Whats wrong with my code? 2015 is Year and 18 is the calendar week?

output is completely wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add week day as well to get the desired output.

Following line should work, where 1 is the first day of week.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2015.18.1', "%Y.%U.%w")
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 0, 0)
```

Here Sunday is assumed as the first day of the week by python because we are using %U. To set Monday as first day of week use %W or refer to documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: hello. thank you. so it isnt possible just to work with the format i have: 2015.18, 2015.19 etc. ?

Comment: "18" would  be the 18th calendar week

Comment: @noob I was also wondering the same. 
here is some text from Python documentation

`For the datetime.strptime() class method, the default value is 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000: any components not specified in the format string will be pulled from the default value`
So I think when we say 18 as the week number but didn't specify any week day it couldn't resolve to a particular date of the year. Thus returning the default date to 1st january of the given year.

Comment: Here is the link for the detailed docs of this method
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)