# Python - Get date from day of week, year, and week number

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have:
a week number
a day of week
a year
I want to find the date from that. How to do it in Python?

e.g. 2020 week1 Saturday
Expected output 01/04/2020

Comment: week is number of week of year or of month?

Comment: Week is the number of week of the year.

Comment: What date handling facilities have you found? What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number)

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use ISO 8601 year and -week directives:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2020 week1 Saturday'

dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%G week%V %A')       

print(dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
# 01/04/2020
```

- [docs: strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: since the question is tagged 'pandas', works here as well: `pd.to_datetime(s, format='%G week%V %A')`.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.8 added the fromisocalendar() method, which is even more intuitive.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt =datetime.fromisocalendar(2020, 1, 6)
print(dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
# 01/04/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it (Based on @MrFuppes's answer) using standard C implementation:

```
s = '2020 week0 Saturday'
dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y week%W %A')
print(dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Bare in mind that the weekdays as well as the weeks - start in zero.