# How to convert dates in the form Year-WeekNumber to datetime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to convert dates in the form Year-WeekNumber to datetimes using strptime. According to the docs I should do it with the formatting code `%Y-%W`, however when I do this it always returns January 1st.

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-11', '%Y-%W')
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-1', '%Y-%W')
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-31', '%Y-%W')
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Why does strptime give the wrong output? Is there another method I can use to handle this conversion?

Edit: Note the suggested question [Python - Get date from day of week, year, and week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568100/python-get-date-from-day-of-week-year-and-week-number) doesn't fit as it doesn't explain why `%Y-%W` wasn't suitable for converting and the input syntax it was using was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. As you can see in the [documentation on `strftime()` and `strptime()` format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), there are two notes next to `%W`. Here, note (7) is relevant.

> 7. When used with the `strptime()` method, `%U` and `%W` are only used in calculations when the day of the week and the calendar year (`%Y`) are specified.

Therefore, you also have to include a day of the week somewhere in your date, otherwise the date is ambiguous. You can include a weekday with `%w`:

> | Directive | Meaning | Example |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `%w` | Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday. | 0, 1, …, 6 |

For example, if you always want to select the Monday of the desired week, you can adapt your code as follows:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-11-1', '%Y-%W-%w')
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 16, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-1-1', '%Y-%W-%w')
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 6, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-31-1', '%Y-%W-%w')
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 3, 0, 0)
```

You can make a simple function to return the Monday based on a Year-WeekNumber input:

```
def get_monday_datetime(week):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime('%s-1' % week, '%Y-%W-%w')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Was expecting it'd error like when %V is used if the syntax was considered incomplete. Fixed it with `datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{week}-1', '%Y-%W-%w')`