# How can I get in datetime week-year?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the follow df:

```
time_series                date   sales
store_0051_item_909446    3/2021    4.0
store_0051_item_909446    4/2021    4.0
store_0051_item_909446    5/2021    1.0
store_0053_item_909446    6/2021    1.0
store_0059_item_909446    7/2021    0.0
```

Being 'date' week/year.
I want transform this field in datetime: week-year.
I tried with the follow code:

`df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%W/%Y'))`

But, return the follow df:

```
time_series                  date       sales
store_0051_item_909446    2021-01-01    4.0
store_0051_item_909446    2021-01-01    4.0
store_0051_item_909446    2021-01-01    1.0
store_0053_item_909446    2021-01-01    1.0
store_0059_item_909446    2021-01-01    0.0
```

What am I missing in the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number)

Comment: Yes, thanks for that! :D

Comment: It's very unclear from Python's documentation that `%W` won't work unless used in conjunction with `w%` - possibly even a bug?

Comment: Yeah, Grismar... make sense, I would like that returned this: W-Y: 45-2020. My doubt is: In datetime this format don't exist?

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['week'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
```