# visualization with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I have the following problem

I want to plot following table:

[image]

I want to compare the new_cases from germany and france per week how can i visualise this?
I already tried multiple plots but I'm not happy with the results:

for example:

```
pivot_df['France'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
pivot_df['France'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))`
```

But it only shows me france

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to get a timeseries plot. For that you'll need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033252/11380795) `year_week` to a datetime object. Subsequently you can `groupby` the country, and unstack and plot the timeseries:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/testing/csv/data.csv')

df = df[df['country'].isin(['France', 'Germany'])]
df = df[df['level'] == 'national'].reset_index()

df['datetime'] = df['year_week'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x + '-1', '%G-W%V-%u')) #https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033252/11380795
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

grouped_df = df.groupby('country').resample('1W').sum()['new_cases']
ax = grouped_df.unstack().T.plot(figsize=(10,5))
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked very well for new_cases how can i now change the table so it shows the comparison between tests_done in germany and france

Comment: just replace the column name here: `grouped_df = df.groupby('country').resample('1W').sum()['tests_done']`

Comment: it shows me on X axes wrong data i add in question.

Comment: It is showing in scientific notation. I have updated my answer to suppress that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

sample df:

```
   Country  week  new_cases
0   FRANCE     9        210
1  GERMANY     9        300
2   FRANCE    10        410
3  GERMANY    10        200
4   FRANCE    11        910
5  GERMANY     9        500
```

Code:

```
df.groupby(['week','Country'])['new_cases'].sum().unstack().plot.bar()
plt.ylabel('New cases')
```

Output:

[image]