# Convet W(Number)-Y(NUMBER) to date in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, datestamp

Using Python:

How do we convert a series of dates W(Number)-Y(NUMBER) in the following format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Example:

```
W01-16
W02-16
W03-16
...
```

To:

```
2016-01-04
2016-01-11
2016-01-18
...
```

Comment: What have *you* tried / researched already, before asking for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapated from [*Get date from week number*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17087314#answers)

- `%w` for day of week, giving `1` to be monday
- `%W` for week of year
- `%y` for year on 2 digits

```
from datetime import datetime

d = "W01-16"
print(datetime.strptime('1-' + d, "%w-W%W-%y"))  # 2016-01-04 00:00:00
```

---

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import Series

s = Series(["W01-16", "W02-16", "W03-16"])
s = s.apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime('1-' + d, "%w-W%W-%y"))
print(s)
```

Comment: It's a long series of dates. The DD that I have shown in the example is relevant to wrt to the day. Could you please show a scalable solution?

Comment: @InVinci what do you mean ? you just have to pass your format here

Comment: @azro Your solution throws this error -- TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: @InVinci You may need to learn how to apply a method on a Series, I'll update my code